# Should I to call super.dispose()?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am learning Dart and Bloc pattern by this [article](https://pranaybhalerao.wordpress.com/2019/06/11/the-bloc-pattern-from-bad-to-acceptable-flutter-code/). In [repo](https://github.com/iamprb/bloc_pattern/blob/master/lib/main.dart) author call `super.dispose();` like:

```
  @override
  void dispose(){
    super.dispose();
    _bloc.dispose();
  }
```

I can't figure out is it optional or requirement call?

Comment: It's not required but it's always a good practice. Doing that you garantee that you call the dispose from the parent class too.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation states for State Dispose

> If you override this, make sure to end your method with a call to super.dispose().

So I would put it below `_bloc.dispose();`

Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html

Comment: It is required in that it is annotated with `@mustCallSuper`, and `flutter analyze` should generate warnings if an override neglects to call it.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`State.dispose`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html) indicates that it is annotated with [`@mustCallSuper`](https://pub.dev/documentation/meta/latest/meta/mustCallSuper-constant.html).  This documents the intended usage, and it will generate a static analysis warning from `flutter analyze`/`dartanalyzer` if an override neglects to invoke it.